# How to stack multiple if statements in Javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

sorry if this has been done before but I couldn't find a question that was relevant enough for my problem.

I'm setting up a simple HTML page with a textbox, similar to what a chatbot would do.
The thing is, I need to display preset answers if precise strings of characters are entered by the user. So far, I'm only able to have two specific outputs : one if a specific string checks in, and one if it doesn't. When I add more, it kinda messes it up where the output goes through several options, when it should only return a specific answer if triggered, and a default answered if not triggered.
If I'm not being clear, here is a visual and my bit of code (might be messy, I'm not an advanced user) :
[visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MaZV.png)

```
        function handleKeyPress(event) {
            if (event.key === 'Enter') {
                processInput();
            }
        }

        function processInput() {
            var inputElement = document.getElementById('input');
            var outputElement = document.getElementById('output');
            var inputValue = inputElement.value;

            // move input to output div
            outputElement.innerHTML += inputValue + '<br>';
            // keep output focus on latest entries
            outputElement.scrollTop = outputElement.scrollHeight;

            // append text after a delay
            function appendTextWithDelay(text, delay) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    outputElement.innerHTML += text + '<br>';
                    // Scroll to the bottom of the output area
                    outputElement.scrollTop = outputElement.scrollHeight;
                }, delay);
            }

            // check for specific strings
            if (inputValue.includes('specific_string')) {
                // output delayed response
                appendTextWithDelay('specific_answer', 1000);
}
            
            else {
                // output delayed default response
                appendTextWithDelay('default_answer', 2000);
            }

            // clear input area
            inputElement.value = '';
        }
```

Thanks in advance !

(Tried stacking "if" conditions with only one "else" check)
(Tried stacking up full groups of "if/else")

Comment: `outputElement.innerHTML += inputValue + '<br>';` this is a self-XSS breach. If you expect only text content and not html markup, use `textContent`. If you expect HTML markup, you probably want to sanitize it.

Comment: Could you explain a bit further please ? What do you mean exactly by "sanitize it", and does it really matter if the webpage is not to be used by a third person outside of me ?

Comment: By sanitizing, I mean remove potential for script execution. Currently someone could execute scripts on your page, for instance by typing `<img src onerror=alert('bad')>`. Even if youvare currently the only user of that page, I'd argue that it does indeed matter. You may someday want 5o include that script in a public page and you won't remember it's dangerous. Of course that's your call at the end.

Comment: Fair point, I'll put that in my to-do. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

When you stack `if` statements you do need multiple `else`s.

```
if (x.includes('a')) appendText('answer_a')
else if (x.includes('b')) appendText('answer_b')
else if (x.includes('c')) appendText('answer_c')
else if (x.includes('d')) appendText('answer_d')
else if (x.includes('e')) appendText('answer_e')
else appendText('answer_default')
```

[Read more on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else#description)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, this is clear and straight to the point, even for a beginner like me. Much appreciated !